# Python regex replace to create smiley faces

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to create a regex string that would turn this text:

```
Hello this is a mighty fine day today
```

into

```
8===D 8==D 8D D 8====D 8==D 8=D 8===D
```

is this possible with a python re.sub oneliner?

Comment: Those are not smiley faces, despite what you may think.

Comment: @Chris: They made me smile anyway...

Comment: Yes, it is possible: `re.sub('.*', '8===D 8==D 8D D 8====D 8==D 8=D 8===D', 'Hello this is a mighty fine day today')`. Sorry, couldn't resist, you might consider stating more clearly what it is you want...

Answer (score 8):

No need for regexes:

```
s = 'Hello this is a mighty fine day today'
' '.join('%s%sD'%('8' if len(w) > 1 else '', '='*(len(w)-2)) for w in s.split())
# '8===D 8==D 8D D 8====D 8==D 8=D 8===D'
```

Edit: debugged ;) Thanks for the pointer @tg

Comment: And now he no longer has two problems. Although this might do interesting things with punctuation...

Comment: and where is `D` for single letters?

Comment: @tg: Whoops, I didn't see that originally. Good you noticed.

Comment: I'd do similar to original: `' '.join(('8' + '='*(len(w)-2) + 'D')[-len(w):] for w in s.split())`

Answer (score 3):

The question is asking for a `re.sub` one-liner, so here is one that does the job:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = "Hello this is a mighty fine day today"
In [3]: print re.sub(r"\w+", lambda x:("8"+"="*1000)[:len(x.group())-1]+"D", s)
8===D 8==D 8D D 8====D 8==D 8=D 8===D
```

For educational purposes only! 8=D

Answer (score 2):

Here is a re.sub oneliner as requested (split for clarity):

```
import re 

print re.sub( r'\w(\w?)(\w*)', \
              lambda m: '8'*len(m.group(1)) + '='*len(m.group(2)) + 'D', \
              "Hello this is a mighty fine day today" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your one-liner (sorry, no regex):

```
for word in sentence.split(' '): print '8' + '=' * (len(word) - 2) + 'D',
```

Comment: it gives `8D` for single letters

Comment: ' '.join(['8%sD' % ('=' * (len(word)-2)) for word in sentence.split(' ') if len(word) > 1])

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any reason to use regular expression as in the previous solutions. Try this instead:

```
def pen(string):
    return ' '.join([("%s%s%s"%('8','='*(len(word)-2),'D'))[-len(word):] \
         for word in string.split()])
```

It seems to work much faster than one of the regex ones that I chose arbitrarily.

Comment: Woops, didn't realize that mhyfritz already posted a non-regex solution. Mine is faster than his until he changes `' '.join(...)` to `' '.join([...])`.